# How to join the result of GROUPBY with the original dataframe in pandas?

Tags: pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

I have a groupby function -:

```
last_sale_value = temp_df_nonzero.groupby(['Key'])['Qty'].last().reset_index() and avg_sale = temp_df_nonzero.groupby(['Key'])['Qty'].mean().reset_index()
```

I want to join this to my original df_1
I was doing -:

```
df_1 = last_sale_value.merge(df_1, on="Key", suffixes=('_salvalx','_salvaly'))
```

Am i doing it right?
I want to join both `last_sale_value` and `avg_sale` to `df_1` on "`Key`" named column

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
 g = temp_df_nonzero.groupby('Key')['Qty']
 temp_df_nonzero['Qty_last'] = g.transform('last')
 temp_df_nonzero['Qty_mean'] = g.transform('mean')
```